# What mathematical background is preliminary for reading and understanding books/papers on wavelets?

Tags: reference-request, wavelets

Please excuse my english. I have had the following math courses for mechatronics engineering education:

- Calculus (single and multivariable)
- Linear algebra (introductory)
- Differential equations (ode's and introductory pde's + Fourier series)

As I read Mallat's paper "*A theory for Multiresolution Signal Decomposition*", I realize that there are gaps in my mathematical understanding of the content. I feel as if I read a poem without catching the meaning between the lines.

PS, I love mathematics and often spend time self-educating myself further than that what is required for the education program.

Comment: basic functional analysis definitely, things like $L^p$ spaces will be covered there. you dont need to go to deep though. Just knowing some definitions and properties will make the reading easier.

Comment: Any course bridging linear algebras and integral calculus would be a good start. This can be done in a course called "transform theory" or "fourier analysis" or something similar. Then to understand more in depth, functional analysis could be nice. If I recall Gilbert Strang has written a more practically oriented engineering-oriented book "wavelets and filter-banks". 

You can learn to use wavelets without understanding all the theory. But if you want to say for example design your own, you will probably want to learn more in depth theory.

Answer (score 1):

The theory of wavelets is a broad field, but looking at your background and the paper you mention I think the book *Funtions, Spaces and Expansions* by Ole Christensen covers everything you need to know.

The prerequisites for reading this book are linear algebra and elementary analysis. The book introduces basic concepts as normed spaces, Hilbert spaces and $L^p$ spaces, and it finishes with a discussion on multiresolution analysis.